# Export push content in Git repository

Tags: git

is there a way to extract (programatically) a file with what will be transmited when doing `git push` ?

I need to get this to import it in a different repo. I think a could generate the patch containing the diff, and the run it the target repo, but is there a way to export / import changes programmatically?

The language of choice can be anything, I just need to know if there is some git command to get the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git format-patch` does exactly what you describe – a single command to give you the differences between current (or any other) HEAD revision, and a given reference revision.

On the importing side, `git apply` is what you want to use.

I don't know how things could be any more programmatically, aside from *actually* pushing to the target repo, or rather pulling from your current into the target one.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it would work. Gonna give it a try. actually pushing it to the target repo not possible for the project I'm working on, since both repos are private and there is no chance of direct communication, or a live connection between one and the other, so I'm looking for somehitng offline. Thanks.

Comment: As hinted, the right thing to do would be *pulling*, rather than pushing, to a local repo, and then pushing to the other private one